# Output custom field value to post string

Tags: php, customization

I am trying to get a custom field called "u-courseid" its a field that was created by a theme plugin. My goal is to output the value of this field after the post name. So the output would be " Post Name (linked to post ) - u-courseid Value " 
I have tried several variations but my PHP skills are very poor.  Would love some insight into this. This is the PHP i need to edit.

```
    echo "<ul>";
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo "<li><a href='".get_permalink()."' title='". get_the_title() ."'>" . get_the_title() . "</a> ";
```

Comment: Hi!
Is `u-courseid` a post meta? how is it saved? you can go `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'u_courseid', TRUE )` for example..

Comment: Hey Samuel,
It is a post meta for a custom post type. That solution looks like it could work let me test this.

Comment: Because this is a custom post type would i need to actually use the ID of this instead of get_the_ID() ?

Comment: Since in the while loop, `get_the_ID()` will return the post ID which you can use to get the meta from database: `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'u_courseid', TRUE )`. Did you test that out?